# Enum_to vs. enum_for in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between `to_enum` and `enum_for` in Ruby? I've been able to use them interchangeably in some instances. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, they aren't treated the same, they are the same.

Comment: If they aren't aliased, they are unlikely to have the same meaning. Even if both have identical implementation for `Object` class, the method could be overridden in subclasses. Nevertheless, I don't know what's the difference between these two methods.

Answer (score 6):

They are mapped to the same method in MRI, `object_to_enum`, so you may use them interchangeably.

```
rb_define_method(rb_mKernel, "to_enum", obj_to_enum, -1);
rb_define_method(rb_mKernel, "enum_for", obj_to_enum, -1);
```

See the source [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_353/enumerator.c#L1917-1918).